# EAS build works fine in Expo Go and simulators but crashes immediately in TestFlight

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I've been using a managed Expo workflow and recently ran EAS build to release it to the App Store, as it consistently works on Expo Go and simulators without any issue. However, according to the crash logs sent back by the review team, as well as when I tried to test it with TestFlight, the app crashes instantly the moment the splash screen is loaded. I've tried npm install expo-modules-core npm install expo-constants but nothing has worked - I'm not sure if it's to do with dependencies that are missing or something else.

I'm using Expo and React Native.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm in a bit of a time crunch.

My dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.17.3",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.5",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.1.0",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.2.2",
    "date-fns": "^2.29.2",
    "date-fns-tz": "^1.3.7",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "expo": "~46.0.9",
    "expo-asset": "~8.6.1",
    "expo-checkbox": "~2.2.0",
    "expo-constants": "^13.2.4",
    "expo-font": "~10.2.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~13.3.1",
    "expo-linking": "~3.2.2",
    "expo-modules-core": "^0.11.8",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.16.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.0",
    "expo-system-ui": "~1.3.0",
    "expo-web-browser": "~11.0.0",
    "firebase": "^9.9.3",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.69.5",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.4.2",
    "react-native-element-dropdown": "^2.3.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-email-link": "^1.14.1",
    "react-native-image-progress": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-onboarding-swiper": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-progress": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.15.0",
    "react-native-svg": "12.3.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.7"
  },
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@types/react": "~18.0.14",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.69.1",
    "@types/react-native-onboarding-swiper": "^1.1.4",
    "husky": "^8.0.1",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest-expo": "~44.0.1",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "pretty-quick": "^3.1.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  },
```

Crash log:

```
Hardware Model:      iPhone11,8
Process:             SGBooths [11145]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A4607790-E69E-4518-B4B9-C22ED20914D4/SGBooths.app/SGBooths
Identifier:          SGBooths
Version:             1.0.3 (4)
AppStoreTools:       14B44
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           SGBooths [1962]

Date/Time:           2022-10-26 14:37:54.8698 -0700
Launch Time:         2022-10-26 14:37:54.6292 -0700
OS Version:          iPhone OS 16.0.3 (20A392)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    5.00.01
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  1

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                         0x1888c2248 __exceptionPreprocess + 164
1   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x181c8fa68 objc_exception_throw + 60
2   SGBooths                               0x104b13ce8 RCTFormatError + 965864 (RCTAssert.m:167)
3   SGBooths                               0x104b9427c -[RCTExceptionsManager reportFatal:stack:exceptionId:extraDataAsJSON:] + 1491580 (RCTExceptionsManager.mm:77)
4   SGBooths                               0x104b94bbc -[RCTExceptionsManager reportException:] + 1493948 (RCTExceptionsManager.mm:147)
5   CoreFoundation                         0x18892ca14 __invoking___ + 148
6   CoreFoundation                         0x1888d8f2c -[NSInvocation invoke] + 428
7   CoreFoundation                         0x1888d8944 -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 64
8   SGBooths                               0x104b466a4 -[RCTModuleMethod invokeWithBridge:module:arguments:] + 1173156 (RCTModuleMethod.mm:584)
9   SGBooths                               0x104b48c90 facebook::react::invokeInner(RCTBridge*, RCTModuleData*, unsigned int, folly::dynamic const&, int, (anonymous namespace)::SchedulingContext) + 1182864 (RCTNativeModule.mm:183)
10  SGBooths                               0x104b488c4 invocation function for block in facebook::react::RCTNativeModule::invoke(unsigned int, folly::dynamic&&, int) + 1181892 (RCTNativeModule.mm:95)
11  libdispatch.dylib                      0x18fd3c4b4 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
12  libdispatch.dylib                      0x18fd3dfdc _dispatch_client_callout + 20
13  libdispatch.dylib                      0x18fd45694 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 672
14  libdispatch.dylib                      0x18fd461e0 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 384
15  libdispatch.dylib                      0x18fd50e10 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 652
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1d51e0df8 _pthread_wqthread + 288
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1d51e0b98 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 1 name:   Dispatch queue: com.facebook.react.ExceptionsManagerQueue
Thread 1 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1c4faa200 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1d51e71ac pthread_kill + 268
2   libsystem_c.dylib                      0x18fda1ca0 abort + 180
3   libc++abi.dylib                        0x1d5129b8c abort_message + 132
4   libc++abi.dylib                        0x1d5119a80 demangling_terminate_handler() + 336
5   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x181c95eec _objc_terminate() + 144
6   libc++abi.dylib                        0x1d5128f28 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 20
7   libc++abi.dylib                        0x1d5128ec4 std::terminate() + 56
8   libdispatch.dylib                      0x18fd3dff0 _dispatch_client_callout + 40
9   libdispatch.dylib                      0x18fd45694 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 672
10  libdispatch.dylib                      0x18fd461e0 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 384
11  libdispatch.dylib                      0x18fd50e10 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 652
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1d51e0df8 _pthread_wqthread + 288
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1d51e0b98 start_wqthread + 8
```

Edit: when I run `npx expo start --no-dev --minify` there's no crash either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: used `expo build` and it worked fine